# How to find the page load time for dynamically rendered pages using angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-analytics, analytics

iam a newbee to this analytics type section, but my requirement is to find the page load time for each dynamically rendered views. Iam using AngularJs as front-end. Iam somehow able to get the page load time for the initial homepage, but when moving into inner pages the time i get is wrong.

Here i used this javascript to find the page load time  and is working only for the initial loading.For the dynamically rendered pages this doesn't work.
Anyone please help me find a solution.

```
window.onload = function(){
setTimeout(function(){
var t = performance.timing;
var sum = t.loadEventEnd - t.navigationStart;
var sec=sum/1000;        
console.log("Time to Load Page: "+sum+" milliseconds);  
}, 0);}
```

Comment: Are you need only JS solution? Chrome DevTools doesn't help you?

Comment: @BordiArt No , actually i want to capture the page load time and display it in a page named statistics page.